# How to consume JSON records from Kafka using Spark Streaming and Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have created a Kafka topic with records in JSON format.

I am able to consume these JSON strings using `kafka-console-consumer.sh`:

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --new-consumer \
    --topic test \
    --from-beginning \
    --bootstrap-server host:9092 \
    --consumer.config /root/client.properties
```

How could I do this using Spark Streaming in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Doh, why Python not Scala?!* Then your home exercise is going to be to rewrite the below code to Python then ;-)

From [Advanced Sources](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#advanced-sources):

> As of Spark 2.1.1, out of these sources, Kafka, Kinesis and Flume are available in the Python API.

Basically, the process is to:

**Read messages from a Kafka topic** using `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11` library as described in [Spark Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide (Kafka broker version 0.10.0 or higher)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html) using `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream`.

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe

val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092,anotherhost:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)

val topics = Array("topicA", "topicB")
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  streamingContext,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)
```

**Copy ConsumerRecords to values** using `map` operator so you won't face serialization issues.

```
stream.map(record => (record.key, record.value))
```

If you don't send keys, just `record.value` is enough.

```
stream.map(record => record.value)
```

**Transform string messages to JSON** Once you have the values, you use [from_json](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@from_json(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema:org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function:

> **from_json(e: Column, schema: StructType)** Parses a column containing a JSON string into a `StructType` with the specified schema. Returns `null`, in the case of an unparseable string.

The code will look as follows:

```
...foreach { rdd =>
  messagesRDD.toDF.
    withColumn("json", from_json('value, jsonSchema)).
    select("json.*").show(false)
}
```

*Done!*

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time out and provide the answer ,I will give it a try and let you know .